# Take user input while running in Matlab

Tags: matlab, input

I have a function that I would like to take input for but only when the user wants to. For example if i have this code:

```
figure
amplitude = 10;
tic
i = 1;
while(1) 
    time = toc;
    values(i) = amplitude*sin(time);
    times(i) = time;
    plot(times, values)
    drawnow
    i = i+1;
end
```

You will get a continually plotting sine wave (like a lame movie). What I want to do is allow the user to change the amplitude of the wave at any time. That is the program will continue to run but if the user types in `20` and `Enter` then the amplitude variable can be changed and the sine wave will change amplitude in the movie. Any pointers on how to achieve this?

Comment: Common guys, the question is well worded and has a good code example. If you upvote it then it will gain some attention and might get answered.

Comment: You won't be able to do this by typing numbers into the console, but you can do it with a simple GUI. Do a google search for Matlab callbacks to get going

Comment: @learnvst Add it as an answer!

Comment: as you wish. There should be a simple GUI tutorial in the Matlab documentations also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably best to do it with a GUI as mentioned, but if you just want something in the console here is what I can offer:

A script that periodically asks the user to input an amplitude and then continues the 'movie' with this amplitude. It can easily be expanded to allow the user to decide when he will be asked to input the next amplitude change.

```
clear
amplitude = 10;
i=1;
while(1) 
    time = i/1000;
    values(i) = amplitude*sin(time);
    times(i) = time;
    plot(times, values)
    drawnow
    i = i+1;
    if mod(i,3141) == 0
        keyboard
    end
end
```

Now this will run for a while and then ask you to input the next amplitude. Note that you can actually give multiple commands at once.

```
amplitude = 20; return
amplitude = 1; return
```

This will let the next amplitude be 20 and the one after that 1. Note that the upward arrow key is your friend here.

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to do this by typing numbers into the console, but you can do it with a simple GUI. Do a google search for Matlab callbacks to find examples. When a GUI event occurs, it triggers a function that you can use to modify the variables in your loop.